# AJAX post returns always 500, cant debug

Tags: c#, ajax, debugging, asp.net-mvc-4

Recently I was faced with some strange server behavior - it started to return a 500 error at several ajax POST requests. All was working fine before. GET requests work fine. I have made Visual Studio trace my code exceptions but I still cannot see requests coming in while debugging. Do you have any ideas?

**Example**

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/home/some-action",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });


        [POST("some-action")]
        public ActionResult SomeAction()
        {
           return new JsonNetResult("success request");
        }
```

**Update**

I use this prefix for my controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("home")]
```

Comment: Many servers are setup to prevent cross site scripting. This may be something you have to setup before it will let you make certain calls. I had a site that only half of the ajax calls worked because of this

Comment: Have you examined the web server log? 500 is a server fault, it may not be executing the service at all or a parameter may be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

So you're using Attribute Routing?

I can't see your Controller but I assume you're missing the `Route` for `/home` in the controller, or removed it from `[POST("/home/some-action")]`

We need more information though. Current assumption is the URL doesn't exist.